# Angular 10 custom orderBy pipe, passing specific value hierarchy, NOT ascending or descending

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to order a list of form objects in angular 10 with a custom pipe, and attempting to order them by an object property with a specific order in mind. The properties, in order, would be `[{VALID: 1}, {INVALID: 2}, {DISABLED: 3}]`. I am passing these as the argument to the pipe in my template. My pipe looks like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Pipe({
   name: 'orderObjectsBy',
   pure: false
})
export class OrderObjectsByPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(array: FormGroup[], sortBy: Record<any, number>[]) => {
      array.sort((a: FormGroup, b: FormGroup) => {
         return sortBy[a.status] - sortBy[b.status]
      })
   }
}
```

`status` can return `VALID`, `INVALID`, or `DISABLED`

My template has an `*ngFor` loop that looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objectList | orderObjectsBy: objectSortOrder; let objectIndex = index"...
```

`objectSortOrder` is equal to `[{VALID: 1}, {INVALID: 2}, {DISABLED: 3}]` in my `component.ts`.

I've tried multiple orders of doing things, changing the `return` to different spots on the pipe, and it just either doesn't show the object list in the UI at all, or doesn't sort.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: DId you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`[{VALID: 1}, {INVALID: 2}, {DISABLED: 3}]` Its an **array** so when you try to do sortBy[VALID] it will return you null. What you need to do is **object** `{VALID: 1, INVALID: 2, DISABLED: 3}`

Also in your pipe `sortBy: Record<any, number>[]` you dont need [] since record it self is object with key and values of specific type. Just change it to `sortBy: Record<any, number>`